# Pairing function $f(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers

Tags: number-theory, functions, polynomials

Is it possible to implement a pairing function using rational numbers, instead of natural numbers? For example $f(0.0008, 0.0016) = \ldots$?

Because, I think Cantor's pairing function only works with natural numbers.